# Skipping saturdays and sundays in javascript and adding non repeated entries to mysql database

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing a rest api using Nodejs which allows users to apply leaves .
The inputs are

1. Number of days as(noOfLeaves).
2. From Date( where I use the day to decide if its weekend and also for skipping month.
3. No of days in the month(for skipping to next month in case).
   I get the month and start day using fromDate.

I am implementing a logic which checks two conditions.
a) Skip to weekdays if its a weekend(sat/sun).
b) Skip to next month if its month end.

My logic below skips weekends but repeats the weekdays. 
What might be the issue, any better approach to achieve this.

```
var splitDat = '2016-05-27'.split("-", 3);
var nxtMonthDay = 1;
var j = 0;
var noOfDaysForThisMonth = new Date(parseInt(splitDat[0]), parseInt(splitDat[1]), 0).getDate();
var noOfLeaves = 5;
for (var i = 0; i < noOfLeaves; i++) {
    var inputYear = parseInt(splitDat[0]);
    var inputMonth = parseInt(splitDat[1]);
    var inputDay = parseInt(splitDat[2]);
    if (parseInt(inputDay) + i > noOfDaysForThisMonth) {
        inputMonth = inputMonth + 1
        inputDay = nxtMonthDay + j;
        j++;
    } else {
        inputDay = inputDay + i;
    }
    var dayVal = new Date(inputYear, (parseInt(inputMonth) - 1), inputDay).getDay();
    // console.log('Day value : ' + dayVal);
    if (dayVal == 6) {
        if ((inputDay + 2) > noOfDaysForThisMonth) {
            inputDay = nxtMonthDay;
        } else {
            inputDay = inputDay + 2;
        }
        // console.log('Saturday');
    } else if (dayVal == 0) {
        // console.log('Sunday');
        if ((inputDay + 3) > noOfDaysForThisMonth) {
            if ((inputDay + 2) > noOfDaysForThisMonth) {
                inputDay = nxtMonthDay;
            } else {
                inputDay = inputDay + 2;
            }
        } else {
            inputDay = inputDay + 3;
        }
    }
    console.log(inputYear+'-'+ inputMonth+'-'+ inputDay);
    //this is a function call to create a leave entry in the database using year-month-day
    ApplyLeave(inputYear, inputMonth, inputDay);

}
```

This gives output as

- 2016-5-27
- 2016-5-30
- 2016-5-31
- 2016-5-30
- 2016-5-31

I am expecting an output as

- 2016-5-27
- 2016-5-30
- 2016-5-31
- 2016-6-01
- 2016-6-02

Can someone tell me if my logic is correct and if not how to do this?

Comment: you could also reconstitute a Date element from your day,month,year variables, and then just extract if it's a saturday or a sunday using Date formatting.

Comment: Can you pls explain with a small example.

Comment: Much easy way to do this one, https://jsfiddle.net/pm3kf099/. Note that the `getMonth()` start with `0`.

Comment: My bad, It worked when i changed the incrementing of inputDay, as  inputDay = inputDay + 1; instead of incrementing the value by i each time.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it, basically your problem is that when you try to see if the date is bigger than the number of days in the months, you use "inputday" + i, but the thing is you don't take into account that you have skipped days with the weekend, so you always increment i by 1 whereas it should be incremented by the number of days skipped, so I have added another variable to fix that, and a bit more logging.

```
var splitDat = '2016-05-27'.split("-", 3);
var nxtMonthDay = 1;
var j = 0;
var noOfDaysForThisMonth = new Date(parseInt(splitDat[0]), parseInt(splitDat[1]), 0).getDate();
console.log("monthdays "+noOfDaysForThisMonth)
var noOfLeaves = 5;
var DaysPassed = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < noOfLeaves; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    var inputYear = parseInt(splitDat[0]);
    var inputMonth = parseInt(splitDat[1]);
    var inputDay = parseInt(splitDat[2]);
    if (inputDay + DaysPassed > noOfDaysForThisMonth) {
        inputMonth = inputMonth + 1
        inputDay = nxtMonthDay + j;
        j++;
    } else {
        inputDay = inputDay + i;
    }
    var dayVal = new Date(inputYear, (parseInt(inputMonth) - 1), inputDay).getDay();
     console.log('Day value : ' + dayVal);
    if (dayVal == 6) {
        if ((inputDay + 2) > noOfDaysForThisMonth) {
            inputDay = nxtMonthDay;
        } else {
            inputDay = inputDay + 2;
        }
         DaysPassed += 2;
         console.log('Saturday');
    } else if (dayVal == 0) {
         console.log('Sunday');
         DaysPassed += 3;
        if ((inputDay + 3) > noOfDaysForThisMonth) {
            if ((inputDay + 2) > noOfDaysForThisMonth) {
                inputDay = nxtMonthDay;
            } else {
                inputDay = inputDay + 2;
            }
        } else {
            inputDay = inputDay + 3;
        }
       DaysPassed++;
    }

    console.log(inputYear+'-'+ inputMonth+'-'+ inputDay);
 }   //this is a function call to create a leave entry in the database using year-month-day
```

jsfiddle to see it working :   https://jsfiddle.net/qvnLzequ/

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick

```
var splitDat = '2016-05-27'.split("-", 3);
var nxtMonthDay = 1;
var j = 0;
var inputYear = parseInt(splitDat[0]);
var inputMonth = parseInt(splitDat[1]);
var inputDay = parseInt(splitDat[2]);
var noOfDaysForThisMonth = new Date(inputYear, inputMonth, 0).getDate();
var noOfLeaves = 15;

for (var i = 0; i < noOfLeaves; i++) {

    if (inputDay> noOfDaysForThisMonth) {
        inputMonth = inputMonth + 1
        inputDay = nxtMonthDay + j;
        j++;
    } else {
        inputDay = inputDay;
    }
    var dayVal = new Date(inputYear, (parseInt(inputMonth) - 1), inputDay).getDay();
    // console.log('Day value : ' + dayVal);
    if (dayVal == 6) {
        if ((inputDay + 2) > noOfDaysForThisMonth) {
            inputDay = nxtMonthDay;
        } else {
            inputDay = inputDay + 2;
        }
        // console.log('Saturday');
    } else if (dayVal == 0) {
        // console.log('Sunday');
        if ((inputDay + 3) > noOfDaysForThisMonth) {
            if ((inputDay + 2) > noOfDaysForThisMonth) {
                inputDay = nxtMonthDay;
            } else {
                inputDay = inputDay + 2;
            }
        } else {
            inputDay = inputDay + 3;
        }
    }
    console.log(inputYear+'-'+ inputMonth+'-'+ inputDay);
    inputDay = inputDay + 1;
    //this is a function call to create a leave entry in the database using year-month-day
    // ApplyLeave(inputYear, inputMonth, inputDay);

}
```